# Rotate/animate cursor -45 Degrees on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cursor

I have a custom cursor ie: `cursor: url(images/cursor.png) 15 15, auto;`

And I would like to animate the cursor rotating -45 degrees and stopping when clicked. And then rotating back when unclicked.

Is there a way to do that in jquery/javascript? or even css but doubting that possibility.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) You [cannot use gif for url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property#Limitations) but you [can try animated SVG](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-ui-3/#cursor) according to docs. Not sure if it works however.

2) Another option is to hide the cursor, use your own DOM element instead and animate it as you want: you can find the example [on css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-cursors/#article-header-id-1)